# Dynamically change font size in react and tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react and tailwind css web app and i wan to integrate a font increaser and decreaser.
I tried multiple ways but couldn't get it work as i cannot override tailwind css text-sm or text-xl using fontSize property in react.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting arbitrary values for the text-size.

According to the documentation of Tailwind:

***Arbitrary values***
*If you need to use a one-off width value that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value.*

```html
<div class="w-[32rem]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You would include your fontSize variable in the [] like so:

```html
<div class={`text-[${fontSize}px]`}>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What i am trying to do is have a 2 buttons which increase and decrease font sizes and if i use ${fontSize}px i don't think it will work for SPAs or? I don't really know how to explain it